# Rails 3: What CSS styles are expected by Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating a custom CSS stylesheet for a Rails 3 application.

Is there a list anywhere of the CSS styles that Rails relies upon? So far I have found:

- #notice
- #error_explanation
- .field_with_errors

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The css for the flash-messages you can choose yourself, as they are normally defined in `application.html.erb` (there is no default definition for flash-messages in rails 3).

For form-styling i would recommend using a gem like [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic), which not only greatly simplifies making forms, but also provides a standard css file. So all needed tags are then known (and can be overwritten if needed).

If on the other hand you are looking at ways to get your complete layout started quickly, you might want to checkout [web-app-theme](https://github.com/pilu/web-app-theme) or [activo](http://dmfrancisco.github.com/activo/) (which is even more complete).

Answer (score 1):

A fresh Rails 3 app will not require any specific CSS class/id styles beyond the three you just mentioned, which is why no default stylesheet is generated until you start scaffolding.

If you run `script/rails generate scaffold MyModel` it will create a stylesheet called `scaffold.css` which the generated views will rely upon.

Comment: Rails also relies on these styles when scaffolding isn't used. For example, if I create a view with a `form_for` and add some validation to the model, a failed validation results in Rails changing the class of the form fields to `field_with_errors`.